# Good practice to include function list at beginning of file

Tags: php, comments

Is it good practice to include a list of functions (in a comment section) at the beginning of a PHP file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.
A good practice is to use - [PHPDoc](http://phpmaster.com/introduction-to-phpdoc/).

Comment: There are actually three styles of commenting, please refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9067163/1117773

Answer (score 1):

Yes it helps to understand what functions this file is using.

You should also comment out what parameters and what return types are there before the actual function code.

Read [here](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.quickstart.pkg.html) for the best practices of php commenting standards on documentor (PHPDOC).

Jeff atwood's [coding without comments](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/coding-without-comments.html) and [When Good Comments Go Bad](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/11/when-good-comments-go-bad.html) posts are helpful for commenting strategy.